# Check that text contains drop and create statements for the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Within T-SQL, commands like `EXEC` and `SP_EXECUTESQL` allow us to execute text strings that contain code. I would like to run a validation across text strings before execution to require that if the text string drops a table then it must also recreates that table.

So this text string would pass:

```sql
DECLARE @good_text = '
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_table
    CREATE TABLE dbo.my_table (
        col1 INT,
        col2 CHAR(1)
    )
'
```

And this text would fail as there is no create table statement:

```sql
DECLARE @bad_text = '
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_table
'
```

And this text would fail because the two table have different names:

```sql
DECLARE @bad_text = '
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_table
    CREATE TABLE dbo.different_table_name (
        col1 INT,
        col2 CHAR(1)
    )
'
```

If I did not need to match the table name, then it would be straight forward to check `@text LIKE '%DROP TABLE%'` and `@text LIKE '%CREATE TABLE%'`.

Something like:

```sql
SET @contains_drop = IIF(@text LIKE '%DROP TABLE%', 1, 0)
SET @contains_create = IIF(@text LIKE '%CREATE TABLE%', 1, 0)
IF NOT (@contains_drop = 1 AND @contains_create = 0)
    EXEC @text
```

But these statements don't extend easily to include the table name. So this method would incorrectly pass the case when the drop and create table names differ.

Outside of SQL I would do this with regex/grep but I am not sure how to do so within SQL.

(Yes, I know there are good reasons not to pass this kind of text to `EXEC` or `SP_EXECUTESQL`. But changing this is not within the current scope, hence why I want to create this additional validation.)

No need for answers to handle `table_name` vs `[table_name]` or `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` vs `DROP TABLE`. I can add all of that text cleaning separately.

**Edit with additional details**

One of our production tasks involves running a significant number of scripts. Rather than do these manually, we have designed a procedure that loops over a metadata table containing all the file names: loads the code within each script (into a variable like `@text` above), validates, and then executes the script (using `EXEC` or `SP_EXECUTESQL`).

As part of the validation, we would like to be sure that `DROP TABLE` statements never occur without a recreating `CREATE TABLE` statement. Ideally this validation occurs at runtime so we can be confident it is always passed before execution.

I am not concerned about malicious code execution. My concern is more to catch mistakes if a script is updated and there is a typo in the table name, or a maintainer includes one statement but fails to include the other.

While I could use a different programming language to validate the scripts, a maintainer could forget to run this or could ignore its results. Hence, the preference to valid at runtime.

While there are alternatives to dropping and recreating a table, not all the maintainers have the skill to use the alternative approaches. And some of those alternatives should have the same validation (for example, I expect to use the same method to check `TRUNCATE` commands are paired with `INSERT INTO` commands).

---

**Edit following answer**

It seems like most of the comments & critique are focused on handling the problem in the most general of situations "of all the ways we could drop and create tables, how can we detect if the same table is dropped and created". This was not the intention of the question - though I can see why it was interpreted this way - hopefully this edit clarifies.

The intended interpretation is: "In the specific instance when tables are dropped and created in the same piece of text using the DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE commands, how can I be sure both commands occur together and both refer to the same table?"

Comment: good luck... wrong place, wrong tools, gonna be tricky.

Comment: "I would like to run a validation across text strings before execution to require that if the text string drops a table then it must also recreates that table" - This is such an unusual requirement, I suggest you have an XY problem...

Comment: Fair points DaleK and MitchWheat, but this is the best option I can see given the wider constraints I am operating within.

Comment: Find a way to generate query plans for all your potential strings and parse through the plan xml for what your after? No idea how I'd go about that specifically, but it's a thought I had.

Comment: "but this is the best option I can see given the wider constraints I am operating within" - which you haven't described. I really think you need to take a step back and tell us the ACTUAL problem...

Comment: Additional context added.

Comment: Reading through the updated description I'd say that your metadata table is a script repository, not a metadata table. Store the table schemas in JSON or XML format and then your stored procedure can generate the DROP/CREATE T-SQL from that, avoiding the need to validate user-supplied (tainted) T-SQL code (or at least reduce the problem scope to ensuring proper use of `QUOTENAME()` so that table and column identifiers are not an issue).

Comment: Expensive, but reliable, brute force solution: For each candidate script, execute the script in a transaction, check for the existence of the table, then rollback the transaction if the table was not recreated (or just record the result of the check if you want to check ahead of really executing).

Comment: Use a CLR function to validate them, then you have access to many .NET string functions.

Comment: I agree with @AlwaysLearning - It would be better if you could store only the details (table names and structures) in your meta data table instead of entire DML scripts.

Comment: I think whatever you're validating is weird. Is DROP TABLE Orders CREATE TABLE Orders a valid script? You're still killing your whole production table. In my previous place of work, we never dropped any tables, they were just changed to x_-tablename. And oh yeah, we had backups too =)

Comment: You probably want to use SMO and the TSqlParser class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-transactsql-161

Comment: This system kind of sounds like a nightmare. Tons of dynamic sql all stored in a table is a recipe for things to go wrong. And then this strange requirement of checking for creating a table after it is deleted. There are ways other than `create table` to create tables. For example, `select into`. That would be nearly impossible to determine using nothing but sql. There are so many gotchas with what you are doing that I don't see anything ever being totally bullet proof which is what is seems you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I know it _seems_ up front like you only care about a small subset of SQL, but you **CAN'T** just check for DROP / CREATE without also understanding how those things might fit in string literals or relative to conditional expressions and nested queries, CTEs, etc, which might be intermixed with every other keyword or command in the language **with unbounded complexity**. Therefore, the work required to do this is _at least_ equivalent (if not worse) to the work required to build a **full SQL parser**.

Comment: Why DROP and reCREATE the tables? Just TRUNCATE them???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think this can solve your issue:

Explanation: What I did is that I prepared 2 temp tables and stored all the table names in them for dropped and created.
Then joined those table and check for null in one and in case of null there is a mismatch.

Scenarios to fail :

1. If table has space in its name.

Handled a scenario where if drop is after create then also fails. Schema is also handled.

```
DECLARE @good_text nvarchar(MAX) =
'   DROP TABLE dbo.my_table1 asdf
    CREATE TABLE dbo.my_table1 (col1 INT,col2 CHAR(1)) 
    CREATE TABLE dbo.my_table2 (col1 INT,col2 CHAR(1))
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_table2
    adf
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_table3 1234ea sdf
    CREATE TABLE dbo.my_table3 (col1 INT,col2 CHAR(1))'
--Select Charindex('Drop Table',@good_text)+10

--Remove Line changes from the script for ease of parsing
SELECT
    @good_text = Replace(Replace(@good_text,Char(13),' '),char(10),' ')

--Remove doulble spaces from the script
WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@good_text) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @good_text = Replace(@good_text,'  ',' ')
END

DECLARE @drop1   nvarchar(MAX) = REPLACE(@good_text,'DROP TABLE','~')
,       @create1 nvarchar(MAX) = REPLACE(@good_text,'CREATE TABLE','~')
DECLARE @dropcount   int = LEN(@drop1) - len(Replace(@drop1, '~',''))
,       @createCount int = LEN(@create1) - len(Replace(@create1, '~',''))
--Select @dropcount, @createCount
IF object_id('tempdb..#drop') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #drop
IF object_id('tempdb..#Create') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Create

CREATE TABLE #drop (
      id         int IDENTITY
    , table_name varchar(1000)
    , WordLoc    INT
    , tSchema    varchar(100) )
CREATE TABLE #Create (
      id         int IDENTITY
    , table_name varchar(1000)
    , WordLoc    INT
    , tSchema    varchar(100) )

DECLARE @TableName varchar(100) 
,       @NewString nvarchar(MAX)
,       @count     int           = 0
,       @storeText nvarchar(MAX) = @good_Text

--Fill Drop table
WHILE (@count < @dropcount)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @TableName =
        SUBSTRING(@good_text
        ,(Charindex('Drop Table',@good_text)+10)
        ,Charindex(' ',(SUBSTRING(@good_text,Charindex('Drop Table',@good_text)+11,LEN(@good_text))))
        )
    SELECT
        @NewString = SUBSTRING(@good_text, CHARINDEX('Drop Table'+@TableName,@good_text)+len(@TableName),len(@good_text))

    INSERT INTO #drop ( table_name, WordLoc )
        SELECT
              @TableName
            , CHARINDEX('Drop Table'+@TableName,@storeText)

    SELECT
        @good_text = @NewString
    --select @NewString
    SET @count += 1
END

SELECT
    @good_text = @storeText

--Fill Create table
SET @count = 0
WHILE (@count < @createCount)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @TableName =
        SUBSTRING(@good_text
        ,(Charindex('Create Table',@good_text)+12)
        ,Charindex(' ',(SUBSTRING(@good_text,Charindex('Create Table',@good_text)+13,LEN(@good_text))))
        )
    SELECT
        @NewString = SUBSTRING(@good_text, CHARINDEX('Create Table'+@TableName,@good_text)+len(@TableName),len(@good_text))

    INSERT INTO #Create ( table_name, WordLoc )
        SELECT
              @TableName
            , CHARINDEX('Create Table'+@TableName,@storeText)

    SELECT
        @good_text = @NewString
    --select @NewString
    SET @count += 1
END

DECLARE @TableTRIM nvarchar(100) = '#drop'
--Ltrim and rtrim all the data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##check') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##check
END
EXEC ('SELECT name, 0 AS done INTO ##check FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..'+@TableTRIM+''') AND is_identity = 0 AND system_type_id NOT IN (SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.types WHERE Name = ''float'')')
WHILE ((SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM ##check
        WHERE done = 0)<>0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @col VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1
                                    '['+name+']'
                                 FROM ##check
                                 WHERE done = 0)
    EXEC ('UPDATE '+@TableTRIM+' SET '+@col+' = ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE('+@col+',''"'','''')))')
    UPDATE ##check
    SET done = 1
    WHERE '['+name+']' = @col
END

SET @TableTRIM = '#Create'
--Ltrim and rtrim all the data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##check') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##check
END
EXEC ('SELECT name, 0 AS done INTO ##check FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..'+@TableTRIM+''') AND is_identity = 0 AND system_type_id NOT IN (SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.types WHERE Name = ''float'')')
WHILE ((SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM ##check
        WHERE done = 0)<>0)
BEGIN
    SET @col = (SELECT TOP 1
                    '['+name+']'
                FROM ##check
                WHERE done = 0)
    EXEC ('UPDATE '+@TableTRIM+' SET '+@col+' = ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE('+@col+',''"'','''')))')
    UPDATE ##check
    SET done = 1
    WHERE '['+name+']' = @col
END

UPDATE #drop
SET tSchema = SUBSTRING(table_name,1,CHARINDEX('.',table_name))
UPDATE #Create
SET tSchema = SUBSTRING(table_name,1,CHARINDEX('.',table_name))

UPDATE #drop
SET tSchema = 'dbo.'
WHERE isnull(tSchema,'') = ''
UPDATE #Create
SET tSchema = 'dbo.'
WHERE isnull(tSchema,'') = ''

UPDATE #drop
SET table_name = REPLACE(table_name,tSchema,'')
UPDATE #Create
SET table_name = REPLACE(table_name,tSchema,'')

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM            #drop   D
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Create C ON C.table_name = D.table_name
        AND c.tSchema = D.tSchema
        AND D.WordLoc < C.WordLoc --If you don't want to fail if drop is after create then comment this section
    WHERE C.id IS NULL
        OR d.id IS NULL
    )
    RAISERROR('Script contains mismatch drop and create',16,1)
```

The [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lcr4zNns) for experimentations

Let me know if you find any different scenarios in this to fail so that I can update the code.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. The only part I am struggling to follow the logic of is the sections `--Ltrim and rtrim all the data`. I tend to use the function `TRIM` to remove white space from text. Please would you explain in more detail the logic/intention of these sections?

Comment: Trimming is just a precautionary step so that no remaining spaces in the name can lead to a problem in joining the tables between dropped and created.

Answer (score -1):

The following handles all three test cases perfectly, and demonstrates the core of the logic I will proceed with:

```sql
DECLARE @input_text NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @drop_found INT
    , @drop_start INT
    , @drop_end INT
    , @create_found INT
    , @create_start INT
    , @create_end INT
    , @drop_name NVARCHAR(500)
    , @create_name NVARCHAR(500)

SET @input_text = '
DROP TABLE dbo.my_table
CREATE TABLE dbo.my_table (
col1 INT,
col2 CHAR(1)
)
'

-- text cleaning
SET @input_text = REPLACE(@input_text, '(', ' (') -- brackets add a space before
SET @input_text = REPLACE(@input_text, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') -- newline becomes space
SET @input_text = REPLACE(@input_text, '  ', ' ') -- double space becomes single space
-- add additional cleaning rules here as required

-- are drop & create commands used
SET @drop_found = IIF(CHARINDEX('DROP TABLE ', @input_text) > 0, 1, 0)
SET @create_found = IIF(CHARINDEX('CREATE TABLE ', @input_text) > 0, 1, 0)

-- locate drop &  create tables
SET @drop_start = CHARINDEX('DROP TABLE ', @input_text) + LEN('DROP TABLE ') + 1
SET @drop_end = CHARINDEX(' ', @input_text, @drop_start)

SET @create_start = CHARINDEX('CREATE TABLE ', @input_text, @drop_end) + LEN('CREATE TABLE ') + 1
SET @create_end = CHARINDEX(' ', @input_text, @create_start)

-- extract drop & create tables
SET @drop_name = SUBSTRING(@input_text, @drop_start, @drop_end - @drop_start)
SET @create_name = SUBSTRING(@input_text, @create_start, @create_end - @create_start)

-- display
IF (
    (@drop_found = 1 AND @create_found = 0)
    OR (@drop_found = 1 AND @create_found = 1 AND @drop_name <> @create_name)
)
    PRINT 'check failed'
ELSE
    PRINT 'check passed'
```

The key idea is to capture the name of the table as the text between the DROP/CREATE command and a closing space. Once we can capture two table names, then we can compare them.

This approach does require that table names do not include spaces, brackets, or newline characters. Which seems a pretty minimal restriction.

Clearly this will need some generalisation to make it robust and capture corner cases, including additional text cleaning.

Comment: You know it's **trivial** to bypass this, right? For example, someone could have a further layer of `exec` or `sp_executesql` nested inside a string literal, and this might never even have the text `DROP` anywhere: just shift the characters in the word `CQNO` by one ascii value over before running the command.

Comment: To reiterate: I know it _seems up front_ like you only care about a small subset of SQL, but you CAN'T just check for DROP / CREATE without also understanding how those things might fit in string literals or relative to conditional blocks and nested queries, CTEs, etc, which might be intermixed with every other keywords or commands in the language with **unbounded complexity**. Therefore, the work required to do this is _at least_ equivalent (if not worse) to the work required to **build a fully functional SQL parser.**

Comment: The question specified the cases that I want to pass & fail. This answer passes and fails those cases. Is that not the whole point of a minimal, complete, reproducible example? I accept the caveat that this answer will only work when the cases look like my test cases. If I was concerned about other test cases then I should have included those in the examples from my question.